# How to create a function which finds a match of a word in a text including with skippings

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I'm in my first steps and currently working on a home-work project (which I actually don't need to send in so there is no hurry in getting answers... but would be nice in any way) - 
(note: I didn't learn any advanced functionality which I asume exists)

I'm trying to write a program to find a word in a text with or without skipping characters and the output in 'main' is the spaces between each character of 'word' found in 'text'

I'm not managing to get the code more efficiant or shorter so that's the call for help about.

here is the shortest iv'e got the function and have it actually work

```
 while (word[indexWord] != '\0' && text[indexText] != '\0' )
 {
    if (word[indexWord] == text[indexText])
    {
        indexWord++;
        indexText++;

        if (firstSame)
        {
            arr[i++] = space; // saving all spaces
            space = -1;
        }

    firstSame=true;//counting spaces only after first found
    }
    else if (word[indexWord] == '\0')
        break;
    else
        indexText++;

    if (firstSame)
        space++;
}

i--;

int sum = 0, sum2 = 0;
while (i > 0 && sum == sum2)// checking that all spaces are equal
{
    sum = arr[i--];
    sum2 = arr[i];
}
if (i==0 && sum == sum2 && word[indexWord] == '\0')
    return sum;
else
    return -1;
```

Program example in main() of how it should look if working properly:

```
Please enter a sentance:
Hello to you
Please enter a word to find in sentance:
eoo
The count of spaces is: 2
```

the result is 2 since there is a skipping over 2 from 'e' to 
'o' and the same from 'o' to the next 'o'

if the word to find in text would be the following:

```
Please enter a sentance:
yesterday
Please enter a word to find in sentance:
xs
The count of spaces is: -1
```

the result is -1 since there is no match.

Comment: `The count of spaces is: 5` should it be `5` or `2`?

Comment: Hi welcome to SatckOverflow. In order for you to get a clear answer you should really make your question clearer. Be more precise on what you want and what is not working.

Comment: What if there were 2 skips to get from e to o and then 3 skips to get to the next o. What should the result be?

Comment: Where does `i` being declared? What does it means?

Comment: @0x499602D2 the program is supose to print number of skippings only if all are the same other then that the result is -1 printed as a false statement, basically I'm looking for a nother approach to solve the problem

Comment: @korelk the approach I took for solving the problem was to count in a array all the spaces and if all are equal the space is printed to the console, the 'i' is the index of array storing the spaces. hope my question is clear, I'll try in asking better questions when I advance

Comment: What if you have `text = "ab---c a-b-c", word = "abc"`? The first subsequence "ab---c" has uneven distances but the second one ("a-b-c") does. What do you want the algorithm to do in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea to save the distances in an array, but you will discover that you don't actually need an array, you can just save the distance between the first two matching characters in `text` and check if the subsequent distances are the same, all while going through both strings in a single loop.

```c++
int solve(string text, string word) {
  if (word.size() > text.size()) return -1;
  int skipVal = -1;
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 0, last = -1; i < text.size() && j < word.size(); i++) {
    if (text[i] == word[j]) {
      if (last != -1) {
        int dist = i - last - 1;
        if (skipVal == -1) {
          skipVal = dist;
        } else if (dist != skipVal) {
          return -1;
        }
      }
      last = i;
      j++;
    }
  }
  if (j < word.size())
    return -1;
  return skipVal;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't solve the example: `solve("Hello to you", "eoo")` returns `-1` instead of `2`. I think you do need the array if you have multiple distances options and not only the first one you see.

Comment: @KorelK I had a few mistakes but it works now. You only need to save the first distance because the OP says all the distances must be the same.